# JSON and OData model in one application. JSON model binding sends request to OData

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm working on an application which uses different models to show a variety of data in an UI5 application.

In Component.js, I define and bind an OData model for general purpose to the application.

```
    var url = my.app.namespace.util.Formatter.configUrl("serviceUrl");
    var dataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true);
```

For a table, I use a JSON model, which is bound in the XML view.

Controller for XML:

```
_updateTable: function(data, tableId) {
    var table = this.getView().byId(tableId);
    var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    jsonModel.setData(data);
    table.setModel(jsonModel);
},
```

XML:

```
<Table
    id="supplierTable"
    fixedLayout="false"
    headerText="Lieferantenübersicht"
    items="{/results}">
```

My problem is that the /results is creating an unnecessary OData call, which I would like to prevent.

I tried to name the JSON Model like this:

```
var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("tableModel");
```

that I use in the XML view:

```
items="{tableModel>/results}">
```

But I get the following error:

```
<p>Problem accessing /EIM_POSTING_RATE/tableModel. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

Any recommendation on how to prevent the OData call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of a named model you need to register it to the view (or the table) in the following way.

```
this.getView().setModel(jsonModel, "tableModel");
```

You need to adapt the property binding to make use of this model. For example:

```
<Text text="{tableModel>text}"/>
```

You trigger an automatic request by using

```
new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("tableModel");
```

because the JSONModel either expects an object representing the data to be stored or an URL which is used to load data.

Comment: Just tested it, `new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("tableModel");` is not the reason for the OData call. You can hand the data directly or call setData, the result is the same. Setting the name in setModel makes sense though. The table is showing all the rows, but they are empty. I have no idea why though. The OData call is gone with that too.

Comment: You need to prepend the model name to each property binding, e.g. {tableModel>property}. Otherwise UI5 tries to bind the specific property against the unnamed model.